# Spring bean injection Icon not being displayed

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm having this issue where intellij not showing spring bean gutter icon. Spring bean has been injected correctly in the xml and when I click on it, it does take me to the injected class. However, I don't see the injection Icon next to the class. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Tried resetting caches, changing modules, doing build, restarted intellij.

Expecting: Spring Icon next to classes where it has spring bean injection

Comment: Make sure that all Spring-related gutter icons are enabled under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Gutter Icons`. Check if the problem reproduces in the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: already done that. Everything is checked correctly :(

Comment: Try using the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download . If the problem remains please contact IntelliJ support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for future assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all Spring-related gutter icons are enabled **Settings/Preferences** | **Editor** | **Gutter Icons** `restart` 
credit @Egor Klepikov